# Moq setup causing null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm new to Unit Testing, and Moq, so if I'm completely wrong in my method or understanding, please assist me.

I have a logic method I am testing. I've commented out the logic, but all it does is check a few values in the 'model' and returns if there's a problem. In the case we're looking at, there's no problem.

```
        public ReplyDto SaveSettings(SnowballDto model)
        {

            // Some logic here that reads from the model.

            var result = _data.SaveSettings(model);
            return result;
        }
```

My test, using NUnit and MOQ, looks like this:

```
_logic = new SnowballLogic(mockSnowballData.Object, mockLog.Object);

           mockSnowballData
                .Setup(x => x.SaveSettings(SnowballDto_Good))
                .Returns(new ReplyDto {
                    IsSuccess = true,
                    Message = "Saved",
                    ReplyKeyID = 1
                });
```

In each test, I call a private setup function that sets up the things I'll be using.

```
 private void SetupData()
        {
            SnowballDto_Good = new SnowballDto {
                FirstPaymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ID = 1,
                OrderedIDPriority = new List<int>(),
                SnowballTypeID = 1,
                TargetPayment = 1000
            };

            DebtDtoList_ThreeDebt.Clear();
            DebtDtoList_ThreeDebt.Add(new DebtDto { ID = 1, Description = "Debt 1", ManualSnowballPriority = 1, MinimumMonthlyPaymentAmount = 140, OpeningBalance = 5000, RunningData = new DebtRunningDto { Balance = 5000 }, OpeningDate = DateTime.UtcNow, SnowballID = 1, StandardRate = 10 });
            DebtDtoList_ThreeDebt.Add(new DebtDto { ID = 2, Description = "Debt 2", ManualSnowballPriority = 2, MinimumMonthlyPaymentAmount = 90, OpeningBalance = 1600, RunningData = new DebtRunningDto { Balance = 1600 }, OpeningDate = DateTime.UtcNow, SnowballID = 1, StandardRate = 15 });
            DebtDtoList_ThreeDebt.Add(new DebtDto { ID = 3, Description = "Debt 3", ManualSnowballPriority = 3, MinimumMonthlyPaymentAmount = 300, OpeningBalance = 9000, RunningData = new DebtRunningDto { Balance = 9000 }, OpeningDate = DateTime.UtcNow, SnowballID = 1, StandardRate = 20 });


        }
```

So, my understanding of MOQ is that I am saying "When the SnowballData class's "SaveSettings" methid is called, and a "SnowballDto_Good" object is passed in, always return a new ReplyDto with IsSuccess = true.

Therefore, when I make the call:

```
var result = _data.SaveSettings(model);
```

It should return ReplyDto with IsSuccess = true

However, when I put a breakpoint in when I call 'SaveSettings', it returns null all the time.

If I change my setup to:

```
.Setup(x => x.SaveSettings(It.IsAny<SnowballDto>()))
```

The test passes. Why is it returning null when I give it a real SnowballDto?

Comment: It compares the argument by reference

Comment: Are you passing the same object used in setup?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the same object.

Comment: We must see more. Where is the `SnowballDto_Good` instance created. Does the type `SnowballDto` override `Equals(object)`, if yes, how? Also, show enough code to convince us this is the same instance of `SnowballDto`. Remember the closure semantics when the lambda in `Setup` is turned into an expression tree.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - I've added how this is done. It's using a Setup function, and I have edited the question to show how it's achieved.

Comment: @Craig, How is setup function being called. manually or test initialize attribute? The OP is not clear. please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi - the setup is being called manually within each [Test] function.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - I'm not sure what is meant by "Remember the closure semantics when the lambda in Setup is turned into an expression tree."

Comment: But is ___one___ `new SnowballDto { FirstPaymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow, ID = 1, OrderedIDPriority = new List<int>(), SnowballTypeID = 1, TargetPayment = 1000 }` equal to ___another___ `new SnowballDto { FirstPaymentDate = DateTime.UtcNow, ID = 1, OrderedIDPriority = new List<int>(), SnowballTypeID = 1, TargetPayment = 1000 }`? The answer depends on whether the class `SnowballDto` overrides `Equals(object)` and how. The most likely explanation is that the Setup is not "met" becuase the argument is not considered a match. A _loose_ mock will just return `null` is no Setup matches.

Comment: Also, two reads of `DateTime.UtcNow` will not give the same value. Time passes; next time you ask for "now" a number of microseconds may have passed, and "now" is changed.

Comment: Thanks. The class does not override Equals.

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems you are passing an instance of `SnowballDto` named `model` in the "act" part of your test

`var result = _data.SaveSettings(model);`

In the setup of moq, however, you configure it to return a new `ReplyDto` only when the instance `SnowballDto_Good` is specified to `SaveSettings`. In all other cases, the method's mock is not configured, and - in case of a loose mocking strategy (the default) - it will return the default value for `SaveSettings` return type. In this case: null.

When you're using `It.IsAny<SnowballDto>` you are basically telling moq to configure `SaveSettings` to return a new instance not only then the instance `SnowballDto_Good` is passed to it, but any instance of that type.

What you need to do is to change your "act" part of your test as follows:

`var result = _data.SaveSettings(SnowballDto_Good);`

then it will work with your original mock setup, because the correct instance will be passed to `SaveSettings`.

This is precisely why I like to instantiate my mocks using MockBehavior.Strict.

Instead of returning null, it will throw an exception that will tell you that you didn't configure your mock correctly.

Hope this helps.